# Eclipse complains about uselessness of elements in layout xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I have a scrollview. A scrollview can only contain one element so I put my RadioGroup and the button below (which acts as a placeholder) inside a TableLayout.

```
 <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow>
                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioStateChoice"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioW"
                            style="@style/CheckboxRadioStyle"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="@string/wien" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioNoe"
                            style="@style/CheckboxRadioStyle"
                            android:text="@string/noe" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioOoe"
                            style="@style/CheckboxRadioStyle"
                            android:text="@string/ooe" />

                        <!-- there are usually more radio buttons -->
                        <!-- I have shortened it to keep the example smaller -->
                    </RadioGroup>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="60sp"
                        android:layout_height="50sp"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Now Eclipse shows me an xml warning: `"The RadioGroup layout or its TableRow parent is possibly useless"`. 
How can they be useless? First of all, I need the radiogroup to access the selected radio button:

```
        int selectedRadioId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedRadioId);
```

And the TableLayout is needed due to the fact, that I can only have one element inside the ScrollView. I chose a TableView because of the placeholder button below. So what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of using table row element  as parent of in table layout.

you can just remove  elelment from xml because  has add the row to Table layout.

Using    as a parent of  is Useless here so eclipse show you a warning of an useless parent for

Comment: You are right, I can omit the TableRows. Didn't know that this works.

Comment: Could you make two or three sentences out of that? It is really hard to understand the never ending lines of words.

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? I just omit the TableRows so I deleted all the <TableRow> and </TableRow> lines and this seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the table is useless as a simple LinearLayout should do the job, too. Also read carefully: `possibly useless` doesn't mean it is useless.

Comment: A LinearLayout doesn't work because the layout doesn't fit then anymore. If it's possibly useless, then it actually shouldn't be a warning.

Comment: I don't get why this shouldn't fit anymore... anyway, good to know that you have found a solution.

Comment: Obviously the placeholder button was somehow ignored so the ScrollView didn't work as expected as with the TableLayout. I wasn't able to get it working with a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think it occurs when you use only one row in a table, the moment I use two or more rows the message disappears. (Why put a only one row in a table, the table itself then is already one row must be the thought behind this).