# Android warning "This TableRow view is useless (no children, no background, no id)"

Tags: android, tablelayout

A warning occours in eclipse when I tried to make a android table layout in xml this warning comes at table row of the layout part:

> This TableRow view is useless (no children, no background, no id)

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>
```

Plese tell me how to overcome this warning.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add android:id=@..., that should take out the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you use this `TableRow` (e.g. you add children to it later in the code) just ignore the warning.

**Upd:** you can't use this `TableRow` in code without id assigned to it. Why do you need the `TableRow`?

Answer (score 6):

That situation appears when you have only one "RowTable" section.

Try to add second empty section, eg.

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
```

In my case it works.

Comment: Really really minor, but the id is missing a closing quote

Answer (score 1):

If you have single table layout then make Table layout parent remove any other parent tag.

You have similar problem try this  [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698978/eclipse-complains-about-uselessness-of-elements-in-layout-xml/8699161#8699161)